# 0 and 1 block in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

[image]

above image. Two constant block to AND operation in simulink.

If we consider the single constant block, I want to automatically change this constant value from  o and 1 as every 2 second.

Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [pulse generator](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/pulsegenerator.html) width the following parameters:

- period: 4 seconds
- pulse width: 2 seconds

Comment: Thank you. so from Pulse generator ... For 2second as 0 and 4 second as 1?

Comment: The pulse generator will output the following: `0s->2s = 1`; `2s->4s = 0`; `4s->6s = 1`. You can use `phase delay` to shift the pulses.